# SQL Query for Repeated category(count items in each category) and has to contain atleast one specific type

Tags: sql, teradata

[image: Example for count items in each category]

SQL Query to perform repeated item_id against each category_id. For this the query would be

```
Select item_id, category_id, COUNT(*) 
from table 
group by category_id, item_id 
having count(*)>1
```

but how can I change the code to filter only ones which have atleast one type A in their repeated counts.

Comment: please show the expected result too.

Comment: Based on your data this query will return an empty result set because the combination of `item_id` and `category_id` is unique.

Comment: @Gordan Thanks it works. I used this as an example. I am not sure if I can extend this query if I have date column as well and want to find the counts only when the dates(of repeated others) are after type A corresponding date in counts as well in addition with `sum(case when type = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the "A"s in the `HAVING` clause as well:

```
Select item_id, category_id, COUNT(*) 
from table 
group by category_id, item_id 
having count(*) > 1 and sum(case when type = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Given your sample data, you can shorten this to:

```
Select item_id, category_id, COUNT(*) 
from table 
group by category_id, item_id 
having count(*) > 1 and min(type)= 'A' ;
```

But this depends on the actual names you are using.

Comment: @Gordan.Lets say I have an other column where there are Dates.Only to have counts when the id and dates dont match.How do I add that condition too?

Comment: @viji . . . You should ask new questions as a *question* not as a *comment*.